# Eloquent: querying using a non-existing column

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, filtering

I'm trying the following: I have two models (Pub and Schedule) related by a 1xN relationship as follows:

### Pub:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function pubSchedules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
}
```

### Schedule:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function pub()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pub::class);
}
```

Table schedules has the following fields:

id | pub_id | week_day | opening_time | closing_time |

I use the following function to know if one pub is currently (or not) open:

```php
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isPubCurrentlyOpen()
{
    $schedules = Schedule::where([
            ['pub_id', $this->id ],
            ['week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek],
    ])->get();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule){
        $isOpen[] =
            Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->between(
                Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time),
                Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)
            );
    }

    if(in_array(true, $isOpen)){
        return true;
        //return "Pub Opened";
    }

    return false;
    //return "Pub Closed";
}
```

In my PubController I'd like, when the option "Filter by open pubs" is chosen `if($request->openPubs == 1)`, to show only opened pubs `isOpen ==true`.

Knowing the relationships between models, how can I do it?

I'm looking for something like this:

```php
 if($request->openPubs == 1)
 {
   $pubs = $pubs->with('pubSchedules')->where('isOpen' == true);
 }
```

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: using $appends and getOpenPubs() in the model should give you the virtual field your looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a "whereHas"

```
$openPubs = Pub::whereHas('schedule', function ($query) {
       $query->where('week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek);
       $query->whereRaw(
           "'".Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->format("H:i:s")."' BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time"
       ); 
})->get();
```

This is assuming your opening time and closing time are the appropriate time format and not strings (though strings will work as well in a 24h format).

You might achieve something similar to what you are looking for by using a scope e.g.

```
public function scopeFilterBy($query, $filter = null) {
     if ($filter == "isOpen") {
        $query->whereHas('schedule', function ($query) {
          $query->where('week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek);
          $query->whereRaw(
            "'".Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->format("H:i:s")."' BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time"
           );  
        });
    }
    return $query; //Not sure if this is needed
}
```

You could then do:

```
 Pub::filterBy($request->openPubs ? "isOpen" : null)->get();
```

Comment: yes this would be the best solution if he wants only open pubs (y)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I may have misunderstood the requirement then

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, just I need what you did. I'm having some problems to implement it, but I hope to solve them. Let me a few minutes, thanks a lot

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy you can read about scopes at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes for more details on the 2nd part

Comment: This error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;........and exists (select * from `schedules` where `pubs`.`id` = `schedules`.`pub_id` and `week_day` = 1 and 2018-06-11 17:15:56 BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time)) in Connection.php (664)" is due to Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')." BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time"...would you know how to solve it?

Comment: I missed the quotes and you missed the `->format("H:i:s")` part. Check the update

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand how you are trying to accomplish this but it should be something like this

```
   $pubs = Pub::with(['pubSchedules' => function ($query) {

        $query->where('opening_time', '>' ,Carbon::now()) // make sure it's currently open
              ->where('closing_time', '<' ,Carbon::now()) // make sure that it's not finished already
              ->where('week_day', '==' ,Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek) // make sure it's today

    }])->find($id);

  // to get if pub is currently

  if($pub->pubSchedules->count()){
      //
   }

   you can put this code in the model (Pub) and make some changes
   if you already have the object you can do this (Add it to model)

public function isPubOpen()
{
    $this->load(['pubSchedules' => 
        // same code in other method
    ]);

    return (bool) $this->pubSchedules->count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For small tables you could call the function `isPubCurrentlyOpen` for each element.

For this you would need to change your function to recieve the pub_id as a parameter:

```
public function isPubCurrentlyOpen($pub_id)
{
    $schedules = Schedule::where([
            ['pub_id', $pub_id ],
            ['week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek],
    ])->get();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule){
        $isOpen[] =
            Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->between(
                Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time),
                Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)
            );
    }

    if(in_array(true, $isOpen)){
        return true;
        //return "Pub Opened";
    }

    return false;
    //return "Pub Closed";
}
```

and to query the data do:

```
if($request->openPubs == 1)
{
   // assuming $pubs is a collection instance
   $pubs = $pubs->filter(function($a){
        return $this->isPubCurrentlyOpen($a->id);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature in Eloquent called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). The Eloquent ORM provides a simple syntax to query for all the Schedules that are related with this particular Pub as described below:

```
$pubIsOpen= $pub->schedules()
  ->where([
        ['week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek],
        ['opening_time' , '<' , Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')],
        ['closing_time' , '>' , Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')]
  ])
  ->count();
if($openPubCount > 0){
    //PUB is open
}else{
    //PUB is closed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps to someone in the future I post my solution, thanks to @apokryfos:

### Pub:

```
/**
 * @param $pubs
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function isPubCurrentlyOpen($pubs)
{
    $pubs->whereHas( 'pubSchedules', function ($pubs) {
        $pubs->where( 'week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek )
            ->whereRaw(
                "'" . Carbon::now( 'Europe/Madrid' )->format( "H:i:s" ) . "' BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time"
            );
    } );

    return $pubs;
}
```

### PubsController:

```
/**
 * @param GetPubRequest $request
 * @return ApiResponse
 */
public function getPubs(GetPubRequest $request)
{
    $orderBy = 'id';
    $order = 'asc';

    $pubs = Pub::withDistance();

    ............


    if($request->openPubs == 1)
    {
        $pubs = Pub::isPubCurrentlyOpen($pubs);
    }

    return $this->response(PubProfileResource::collection($pubs->orderBy($orderBy, $order)->paginate()));
}
```